# Prisma nested query

Tags: mysql, node.js, prisma

I've a query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS mock_test_count 
FROM mock_test 
WHERE isActive = 1 
AND id NOT IN ( SELECT mock_test_id 
                FROM mock_tests_given_by_students 
                WHERE student_id = 2 )
```

I'm using prisma orm.

already gone through the docs of nested query in prisma, but didn't found any solution. I can solve the query using 2 different prisma query, but I want to it in a single prisma function. Is it even possible via prisma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite it without a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS mock_test_count 
FROM mock_test a
LEFT JOIN mock_tests_given_by_students b
  ON b.mock_test_id = a.id
  AND b.student_id = 2
WHERE a.isActive = 1 
AND b.mock_test_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(mt.*) AS mock_test_count 
FROM mock_test mt
INNER JOIN mock_tests_given_by_students  mts
ON mt.id = mts.id AND mts.student=2
WHERE mt.isActive = 1
```